# Openstack instance cannot access external network

Tags: openstack, openstack-neutron

I followed [RDO:neutron-with-existing-external](https://www.rdoproject.org/networking/neutron-with-existing-external-network/) to install an openstack env on VirtualBox Instance(CentOS7). After that, I logged into openstack and created an cirros instance to check connectivity with external network. Then, weird thing happened.

PING PASS (with floating IP address): 
1. VirtualBox instance (where installed openstack) <-> Cirros Instance 
2. My laptop <-> VirtualBox Instance

PING FAIL: 
1. My laptop cannot ping the Cirros Instance
2. The cirros Instance cannot ping my laptop
3. The cirros Instance cannot ping external gateway

Is there anybody can give me some suggestions or guide?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, I find the answer by myself. The root cause is my PROMISC mode is not enabled. I wrote a note for this issue. ([RDO Stack:VMs cannot access external network.[1](http://blog.csdn.net/yexianyi/article/details/50685844))